# Iterator for read binary file

Tags: c++, iterator

I have to read some binary file in blocks of 8 bytes and then send those blocks by tcp socket.
Can I use C++ iterator for this task? Like:

```
 FileIterator file("name_file.bin");

for(iter = file.begin(); iter != file.end(); iter++) {
    sendTcp(iter);
}
```

Class `FileIterator` has to return some struct which will be sent.
In constructor of `FileIterator` I open binary file and read it. Then I create dinamic array and write in it file's content. And in each step iterator I have to read next block from array and write it in struct and return.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: TCP don't give a crap that you're feeding it chunks of 8 bytes. It will buffer those chunks and send what it wants, when it wants.

Comment: This looks like a lot of work to do something simple. [std::istream::read()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) was designed for this.

Comment: Also what happens if the file size is not divisible by 8? Iterators would fail to read the last part of the file in that scenario.

Comment: I have to add some header for each block. Algorithm like so: 1. read 8 bytes from file - add to them header - send it. 2. read next 8 bytes - add header - send ... until the end of the file.

Comment: Galik, if file is not  divisible by 8 then the last massage will not equal 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I see this as an X-Y problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Yes, it can be done with an iterator, but iterators aren't the best fit solution for this job. Using an iterator for this is an interesting educational experience, but going old school solves this problem with almost zero fuss and much easier error resolution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// simple 8 byte struct
struct EightByteStruct
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
};

// quick hack send routine. Added capacity for some simple error checking.
bool sendTcp(EightByteStruct & test)
{
    bool rval = false;
    // send test. Set rval true if success
    return rval;
}

//main event: read file into struct, write struct to socket
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("filename", std::ios::binary);
    EightByteStruct test;
    while (in.read((char*)&test, sizeof(test)))
    { // will not enter if sizeof(test) bytes not read from file
        if (sendTcp(test))
        {
            // handle send error
        }
    }
    // test here for any file error conditions you wish to have special handling
}
```

Comment: Yeap I think about something like that you've written. But, probable I'll make by different way, In class I write method which will return bool state: true - there is some block, false - there is no any blocks. And it method also will be take variable in which will be written block from file with header.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can!

You can use fstream with istream_iterator, like so:

```
auto f = std::ifstream("lol.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
f.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);
for (auto start = std::istream_iterator<char>{ f }, end = std::istream_iterator<char>{}; start != end; ++start)
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**
I haven't notice you asked for 8 bytes block. The way you can solve it is like this:

First define an operator>> for example:

```
struct My8Bytes {
    char bytes[8];
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, My8Bytes& bytes) {
    s.read(bytes.bytes, sizeof(bytes.bytes));
    return s;
}
```

and than use the the iterator the same way as before, only now with your specific type:

```
for (auto start = std::istream_iterator<My8Bytes>{ f }, end = std::istream_iterator<My8Bytes>{}; start != end; ++start)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure you want to use exceptions here. To be honest, not sure you want to use `istream_iterator<char>`, either. `istream_iterator<OP'sUnspecified8ByteStruct>` is probably a better fit. But it's coming out of a file so endian and other nastiness needs to be accounted for and `istream_iterator` won't do that.

Comment: @user4581301 hypothetically, you are right. I just simplified it to the most default concert solution. The logic behind my decisions were that C++ is an exception based language and char is the type used in fstream.